# A doubt in a theorem about group extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology, group-extensions

I am reading [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S030402080970146X) chapter.

Part 1 in theorem 1.2 tells us that

Let $E : 1 \to A \xrightarrow{i} X \xrightarrow{f}  G \to 1$ be an extension of $A$ by $G$ let $t : G \to X$ be a section of $f$ i.e. $t(1) = 1$ and $f \circ t = 1_G$.
The formula ${^x a} = t(x)at(x)^{-1}$ determines an action of $G$ on $A$, which depends only on the equivalence class of $E$.

I am able to prove that the given formula gives an action. Now I want to prove that it only depends on the equivalence class of $E$.

If $E' : 1 \to A \xrightarrow{i} Y \xrightarrow{g}  G \to 1$ is another extension that is equivalent to $E$, then without loss of generality, we may take $X=Y$ and $f=g$.
Suppose $s$ is another section of $f$, and $ x * a $ denotes the corresponding action. I defined $\phi : A \to A$ given by $a \mapsto t(x) s(x)^{-1} a s(x) t(x)^{-1}$. It is easy to see that $\phi(x*a) = {^xa}$. Also, I verified that $\phi$ is injective and surjective as follows:
$$\phi(a) = \phi(b) \implies t(x) s(x)^{-1} a s(x) t(x)^{-1}=t(x) s(x)^{-1} b s(x) t(x)^{-1} \implies a = b.$$

Given $b \in A$ we see that $\phi(t^{-1}(x) s(x) b s^{-1}(x) t(x)) = b$.
So $\phi$ is bijective and preserves group actions.

My doubt is that I have not used the fact that $s$ and $t$ are sections. Where I am missing?

Note : The same question is asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437130/a-doubt-in-a-theorem-about-group-extensions).

Comment: Was it your intention to write $i$ for both of the injections $A \xrightarrow{i} X$ and $A \xrightarrow{i} Y$?

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic, does it matter? (where both extensions are equivalent).

Comment: Well, your doubt about a proof which does not use an important hypothesis is certainly justified. So I'm starting at the beginning and looking for obvious flaws to fix. The first flaw I spotted was this one. And, regarding your comment, it is certainly false that if $A \xrightarrow{i} X$ and $A \xrightarrow{j} Y$ are two injections, and if $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$, then $i=j$. That seems like something easy to fix, particularly given that your question at its root is about the delicate relation between isomorphism and equality.

Comment: Lspice commented here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437130/a-doubt-in-a-theorem-about-group-extensions?noredirect=1#comment1126524_437130   " It may be as simple as that you don't even have an action unless s and t are sections". We need $t$ as a section to show that ${^xa} \in A.$